# Editing Stored Procedure and Updating table Adapter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tableadapter

I just updated the stored procedure by adding one more column then i went to table adapters and recreate the table adapter but the updated column wont appear in data columns.. How can i fix this issue? Please Help...

Comment: I have faced sometimes the above. In order not to loose time i delete the adapter and add it again. This is not the best practice, of course but when time is pressing is a solution.

Comment: please add more details (your stored procedure , code) in order to help you

Comment: i strongly suggest you add your code and some more details, but i think that if you just pass in step by step to create the adapter, you will find your mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you can paste some code here so we can provide better assistance.

For a start just make sure you committed changes to your stored procedure, that you added procedure to the correct database and such.

If that’s working fine try deleting and creating adapter again from scratch. If that still doesn’t work you can always add column manually and bind it to appropriate output column.

Comment: thanks restarting VS and recreating the adapter solved the problem